# Why does terminal auto complete sometimes not suggest anything for the `services` command?

Tags: bash, vsftpd, auto-completion

Sometimes, when I type a command on the terminal, the terminal's autocomplete does not work, even if my command is not wrong.

For example, take look to this: `sudo service vsftpd status` sudo and service do not have any problem. I mean, when you type **sud** +<kbd>tab</kbd> terminal suggest you **sudo** or I type **servi** + <kbd>tab</kbd> terminal complete that to **service**. But for vsftpd I do not get any suggestion. Is there a way to say, "terminal, please tell me any suggestion!!?".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The degree to which auto-completion works is a function of how well the shell scripts in the `bash-completion` package work.

In Ubuntu 14.04, the script that handles completions for `service` is in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.  It looks for service names as files in `/etc/rc.d/init.d` and `/etc/init.d`, and in the output of `systemctl list-units --full --all`.

But installing the `vsftpd` package doesn't put any files in `/etc/init.d`, because it has been `systemd`-ified; it puts a config file in `/etc/systemd/system/vsftpd.service`. `systemctl list-units` would find that file if not for the fact that Ubuntu, at the present time, doesn't include a `systemctl` command.

So, at the moment, you won't get auto-completions for `service vsftpd`, but you will for most other services, since their config files are in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: For those who find this answer: Completion finding services (and time to find/parse) has always been a problem under 14.xx, 16.xx 18.xx : Good example: `sudo systemctl `(status or stop)`lightd` (TAB/Double TAB) (Meaning complete 'lightdm.service' assuming you have it installed - active/running or not) 
This svc is both in units output and `/etc/init.d` on my machine. I have found same issue on other services as well. There is also a bug(?) that makes it take a long time on completions. Seen it sit 10+ secs before beeping at me/not found. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7185

Answer (score 11):

When there are multiple possible suggestions, <kbd>tab</kbd> will not produce any suggestion. Using <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> (double tab) will produce a list of all possible suggestions.

Comment: I used:tab + tab does not work for vsftpd. You and Rinzwind's suggestion is work for example su + tab + tab. But for vsftpd does not work.

Comment: you can test that first install small program vsftpd by sudo apt-get install vsftpd and then try tab + tab

Comment: tab+tab does not work in case of parameters. In `sudo service vsftpd status`, the vsftpd is a parameter of service, and therefore will not be found with a double tab. The OP is correct at this point.

Comment: @Jos But other services like `apache2` and `networking` autocomplete. How are they different?

Comment: @dan08 I stand corrected. Moreover, `sudo service networking tab tab` will offer `force-reload reload restart start stop`. So it works even better than I thought.

Answer (score 6):

vsftpd has probably more than 1 option. <kbd>tab</kbd> twice to view the possibilities.

Example: `li` with <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> shows:

```
libnetcfg          line               lintian-info       lispmtopgm
libreoffice        linguist           linux32            listres
lightdm            link               linux64            
lightdm-session    lintian            linux-boot-prober
```

Answer (score 4):

You can build your own!

E.g.:  put `complete -f -r -c su -d 'Username' -a '(cat /etc/passwd|cut -d : -f 1)'` into bash than if you have `su` and press tab/tab it gives you all users, yeah. See [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/complete/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `systemctl list-units --full --all` does not list disabled services, so autocompletion doesn't

```
# check if enabled
systemctl is-enabled <service_name>
# enable
systemctl enable <service_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The services command relies on "systemctl list-units --full --all", and does not list services that are unable to start (or disabled as above), to confirm if you experiencing this issue you can run

```
systemctl status <service_name>
```